# Send Javascript array when submitting form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I would like to submit the form using Javascript, and with the form I would like to send also one Javascript array.
So far I have this which is not working (I don't get the modified URL and I get the one specified in the action property of the form):

```
<script>
    function submit_form() {
        var unique_id_to_delete = [];

        if (confirm('Remove records ID: ' + unique_id_to_delete.toString() + '?')) {

            document.getElementById("submit_form").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var url = 'submit.php?id_delete='+unique_id_to_delete.toString();
                window.location.href = url;
            });

        } else {
            alert('Ok, next time!');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form id="submit_form" method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="button" onclick="submit_form();" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? (Make sure you look at the JS error console and the HTTP request content in the developer tools when describing this).

Comment: It's not working because it's not in the correct format. You want your query string to be something like: `?id_delete[]=value1&id_delete[]=value2` PHP will interpret this as an array.

Comment: I modified the question. Hope that now my question is understandable.

Comment: ninty9notout, the problem is that even if I specify the URL in Javascript as banana.php, it will still submitting the form to submit.php... Looks like this piece of codewhere I specify the customized URL is never read..

Comment: Stick `return false;` before the end of the function to stop the event from propagating, thus stopping the default browser behaviour of submitting the form to the URL specified in the `action` attribute.

Comment: no it is not working..

Comment: Sorry - my bad, I gave some wrong advice. Please see this fiddle for an updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/eop9020h/

Comment: Ok, but correct me if I am wrong, but this will send only the data in the URL and will not post the form?

Answer (score 0):

Form submit using javascript

```
        function submit_form()
        {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                  //response after success
                  //xmlhttp.responseText
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR URL WITH PARAMS",true);
            xmlhttp.send();


        }
```

Comment: But his will not submit the form...?!

Comment: create an array of values.then "var data1 = JSON.stringify(YOURVALUES);" then submit values like this $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {value1:data1},
            url: "URL",
            success: function() { // success }
            });

Answer (score 0):

Heh.. ok I tried this which I think is not what you thought..

```
<script>
    function submit_form() {
        var unique_id_to_delete = [];

        if (confirm('Remove records ID: ' + unique_id_to_delete.toString() + '?')) {

            var data1 = JSON.stringify(unique_id_to_delete);
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", data: {value1:data1}, url: "submit.php", success: function() {  
                 } });

        } else {
            alert('Ok, next time!');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

script:

```
function submit_form() {
var unique_id_to_delete = [];
    if (confirm('Remove records ID: ' + unique_id_to_delete.toString() + '?')) {    
            var url = 'submit.php?id_delete='+unique_id_to_delete.toString();
            alert(url);
            window.location.href = url;            
    } else {
        alert('Ok, next time!');
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<form id="submit_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="button" onclick="submit_form();" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form will never but submitted as your are simply redirecting the window location, thus creating a GET rather then a POST as intended.
You could do:

```
function submit_form() {
  var unique_id_to_delete = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

  if (confirm('Remove records ID: ' + unique_id_to_delete.toString() + '?')) {

      $.ajax({
          url: "submit.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: unique_id_to_delete,
      });

  } else {
    alert('Ok, next time!');
  }
}
```

And not need a form:

```
<input type="button" onclick="submit_form();" value="Submit"/>
```

I haven't used PHP in a while, but at the other end you need to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)